# How to access an application through java?

Tags: java, skype

I want to access the [Skype](http://www.skype.com) application installed on my pc through a java program so that I can access the "Search for people on skype" feature of the application so as to search for skype users through the program and not manually.

So how can I get control of the application through java.

Comment: Similar question in the sense that my answer over there applies to this question too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354186/detect-if-certain-software-is-installed-on-a-users-machine-in-java

Comment: Esko, Skype should be accessed through its API, not as a command line invocation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [Skype API](http://sourceforge.jp/projects/skype/releases/) library for JAVA. Not sure if it is still maintained...

Comment: I'd love to hear from people with actual experience with this library.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on Windows, you may be able to access Skype via a Java-COM bridge, e.g. [JCom](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jcom/), [JACOB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/) or [J-Integra](http://j-integra.intrinsyc.com/).
Beyond this technological requirement you need to find API for the feature you are looking for. This is probably the more uncertain part - if there is none, well good luck ;)